# How can I get this query to work?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

The query asks to find the course sets that their combination covers all the missing knowledge/skills for a person to pursue a pos_code. The considered course sets will not include more than three courses. If multiple course sets are found, list the course sets (with their course IDs) in the order of the ascending order of the
course sets’ total costs.

The query I'm trying to write is below, but is throwing an error inside of SQL Developer. SQL Error: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification. What is the cause of that?

```
SELECT c.c_code, c.title, c.level, c.description, k.ks_code, SUM(c.retail_price)
FROM course c 
INNER JOIN knowledge k 
ON c.c_code = k.c_code 
INNER JOIN requires r 
ON r.ks_code = k.ks_code
WHERE pos_code = 1
GROUP BY c.c_code, c.title, c.level, c.description, k.ks_code
ORDER BY c.retail_price;
```

The tables that are used are

```
CREATE TABLE course(
    c_code VARCHAR(8),
    title VARCHAR(80),
    c_level VARCHAR(20) CHECK(c_level = 'beginner' OR c_level = 'intermediate' OR c_level = 'advanced'),
    description VARCHAR(300),
    status VARCHAR(6) CHECK(status = 'expired' OR status = 'active'),
    retail_price NUMERIC(8,2) CHECK (retail_price > 0),
    PRIMARY KEY(c_code)
);

CREATE TABLE knowledge(
    ks_code VARCHAR(8),
    ks_title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ks_description VARCHAR(300),
    ks_level VARCHAR(15) CHECK(ks_level = 'beginner' OR ks_level = 'intermediate' OR ks_level = 'advanced'),
    PRIMARY KEY(ks_code)
);

CREATE TABLE requires(
    pos_code VARCHAR(8),
    ks_code VARCHAR(8),
    PRIMARY KEY(pos_code, ks_code),
    FOREIGN KEY(pos_code) REFERENCES position ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(ks_code) REFERENCES knowledge ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE teaches(
    c_code VARCHAR(8),
    ks_code VARCHAR(8),
    PRIMARY KEY(c_code, ks_code),
    FOREIGN KEY(c_code) REFERENCES course ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(ks_code) REFERENCES knowledge ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE position(
    pos_code VARCHAR(8),
    emp_mode VARCHAR(15) CHECK(emp_mode = 'full-time' OR emp_mode = 'part-time'),
    required_skill VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    pay_rate NUMERIC(8,2) CHECK(pay_rate > 0),
    pay_type VARCHAR(8) CHECK(pay_type = 'wage' OR pay_type = 'salary'),
    cate_code VARCHAR(8),
    comp_id VARCHAR(8),
    PRIMARY KEY(pos_code)
);
```

Comment: "isn't really working" is not a useful description. Please expand on how it isn't working, by posting a sample input dataset (what's in the tables), a sample output data set (the thing that isn't working), and what you want (how tell that it is working)

Comment: Wha-what? Why isn't working? Do you get an error, or the result is wrong? Please show some an example of input data and expected result.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. When I run this query inside of oracle sql developer, I receive the error SQL Error: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification. What is the cause of that?

Comment: @RyanP, you need to add your `position` table as well and provide some sample data

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Please google for answers--including for error messages--before you think of asking.

Comment: The question is done with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query was not even properly framed, there were a lot of mistakes in the column references which were missed.

The query is now fixed which were having wrong column references earlier!

```
SELECT c.c_code, c.title, c.c_level, c.description, k.ks_code, SUM(c.retail_price)
FROM course c 
INNER JOIN knowledge k 
ON c.c_code = k.ks_code 
INNER JOIN requires r 
ON r.ks_code = k.ks_code
WHERE r.pos_code = 1
GROUP BY c.c_code, c.title, c.c_level, c.description, k.ks_code, c.retail_price
ORDER BY c.retail_price;
```

You still need to check for the following points:

- You need to check which `pos_code` you want to refer to. Is it from `requires` or `position`?
- Run this query for data, I have just checked for the query to execute!

Answer (score 0):

There is no column level in table course and there is no column c_code in table knowledge

Comment: So to really fix this error, I already corrected the mismatch column names, but for c_code in the knowledge table, would it make sense to add a c_code inside of it? I added another table above that seems like it would be a better fit.

Comment: Yes it looks like the link between course and knowledge is the teaches table.